# What is the Difference Ask Ubuntu and A.U. Meta?

Tags: discussion

What is the difference between this site, Ask Ubuntu, and Ask Ubuntu Meta?

Answer (score 8):

The [FAQ](http://meta.askubuntu.com/faq) does a great job explaining the differences:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> This site is for [meta discussion](http://meta.askubuntu.com/about) about [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com). Any question relevant to our community is welcome here. For example, things like:
>
> 1. Are questions about **_** on or off topic?
> 2. What should our FAQ contain?
> 3. How should we tag questions about **_**?
> 4. What should our elevator pitch be?
> 5. What should our site design look like?
> 6. Who should the moderators be?
> 7. How do we promote our site?

Answer (score 6):

AskUbuntu Meta is a site where questions (such as this one) should be posted to ask about AskUbuntu itself.

From the [about page:](https://meta.askubuntu.com/about)

> The FAQ explicitly disallows meta-discussion on the main site, to
>   reduce clutter and noise. This frustrated many members of the
>   community who wanted to ask questions about how and why the website
>   works the way it does. We needed an outlet for this activity, a
>   separate place where community members could go for sanctioned
>   meta-discussion. And here it is!
>
> The focus of this site is the content topic. If the question is about
>   the Stack Exchange engine in a general sense, it should be asked on
>   Meta Stack Overflow instead.

[Here is](https://meta.askubuntu.com/faq) the FAQ page where you can learn more.

Comment: Great. Thanks for all the answers! I 100% understand now.